# ASP.net core - Same action, two views: one paramater is null but the other is fine

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have two different views and one controller. There is a date picker combobox on both. It works on one view but not the other.

Model #1:

```
public class TripDate
{
    public List<DateTime> listDates { get; set; }
    public DateTime? selectedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Model #2

```
public class AdminManageModel
{
    public TripDate date { get; set; }
    public string FormMessage { get; set; }
}
```

This code works fine in the view ChooseDate.cshtml

```
@model TripManagement.Models.TripDate    
<form asp-action="ChooseDate" method="post">
        <select asp-for="selectedDate">
            @if (Model.listDates.Count == 0)
            {
                <option>-</option>
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var date in Model.listDates)
                {
                    <option>@date.ToString("d")</option>
                }
            }
        </select>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The above calls this action:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ChooseDate(string selectedDate)
{
    return RedirectToAction("TripManage", new { selectedDate = selectedDate });
}
```

The string "selectedDate" has a value. My problem is when I try to call this same action with another view called AdminManage.cshtml, the string selectedDate is NULL. I'm fairly new at this MVC business so I thought maybe it was related to some sort of behind-the-scenes model binding stuff I'm unaware of. I tried making a separate action entirely to do the same thing:

AdminManage.cshtml

```
@model TripManagement.Models.AdminManageModel    
<form asp-action="AdminManage" method="post">
        <select asp-for="date.selectedDate">
            @if (Model.date.listDates.Count == 0)
            {
                <option>-</option>
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var date in Model.date.listDates)
                {
                    <option>@date.ToString("d")</option>
                }
            }
        </select>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Which calls the below action (exactly the same as the ChooseDate above):

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AdminManage(string selectedDate)
{
    return RedirectToAction("TripManage", new { selectedDate = selectedDate });
}
```

**In this action, selectedDate is always NULL.** I cannot figure out why this is happening. Something somewhere is failing to map correctly but as this is my first MVC project, I have no good idea how to troubleshoot this further. The difference between the two views ChooseDate.cshtml and AdminManage.cshtml is that they use different Models, but the model properties should nevertheless work here, no?

I appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that you changing the value in your "asp-for" attribute, without adapting your server side method.

Your first example is different to your second one:

```
<select asp-for="selectedDate">
<select asp-for="date.selectedDate">
```

This means that your form will post "date.selectedDate" instead of "selectedDate" hence why your model binding is failing.

Try modifying your "AdminManage" method to:

```
public IActionResult AdminManage([Bind(Prefix="date")]string selectedDate)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried modifying the AdminManage method as you have described. However, the string selectedDate is still null. (Also it just occurred to me the selectedDate is a string and not a Datetime? type as indicated in the asp-for in both of the forms. Coming from desktop development, I'm not too familiar with types just changing around on their own)

Any more ideas?

Comment: Alright well I after some more googling, I got both actions to work by instead passing in the relevant Model instead of a string selectedDate. This appears to be in line with MVC conventions but feel free to let me know otherwise. I guess MVC was on its own able to determine that model TripDate and string selectedDate should be bound, but model AdminManage and string selectedDate should not?